# IOS Html5 Test App - Compile and email?

Tags: ios, xcode, html, cordova

Our manager is on the road and has managed to arrange a meeting with a client that he could potentially sell a version of a HTML5 app we have built to - he asks whether it is possible to compile and send as an app that he can install on his phone to demonstrate.

I have built the app in Xcode and have a Apple developer licence - but have so far only ran the app on my phone via connecting it to my mac - is it possible to compile and send?  I'm guessing not as I cant find any info on how to do so. But if so how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add your manager's device to your team's provisioning profile, have him install the profile on his device, then re-build the application using the new profile and have him install the signed app. See Apple's [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DevelopingAppsThatRequireCertificatesandProvisioning/DevelopingAppsThatRequireCertificatesandProvisioning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH3-SW1).

It's a bit of a process which will take time to nail down, however there are excellent services out there that greatly facilitate the process. [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com/) is an example of such a service.

Comment: Cheers Andre, my manager can barely work a toaster so it could be a tricky one if he has any thing techy to do - but i'll take a look through the docs and services

Comment: In terms of what your manager physically has to do, it's really just clicking links—especially so if you take the TestFlight approach.